# php mysql query for house types

Tags: php, mysql, database

First of all I apologise for the title of the question as I am not completely sure what this kind of query is called in mysql.

OK SO I have a large database 700,000 + records containing overseas property / real estate listings.

NOTE : I am using mysql pdo with prepared statments in the actual live site .

I have the following query

```
$propertyType = 'House';
//// This is generated from a drop down with possible values of House, Apartment & Land

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM PropertyTable WHERE 
        PropertyType = $propertyTpye'
```

Now This query works fine when the property is listed in the database as a house, apartment or land. My problem is that The database is populated from several xml feeds from multiple estate agents around the world and these estate agents call things differently.

For example in the UK a house is called a house else where a "house" can be called a "villa", a "town house", "detached house", "chateau", "mansion" etc.

And then for Apartments there can be "Apartment", "flat", "penthouse" etc.

What is the best solution for search the database table. I do not want to put all these options in the drop down menu because its getting to sepecific and will not return enough results.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How do your agents insert that `propertyType` do they type it in or do they have a drop down ?

Comment: The agents supply me with an xml feed with a string value for property type. So I cant control anything there side

Comment: You should normalize the XML data *before* uploading it into your database.

Comment: So they give you a XML file and you upload the file to the data base am I right ?

Comment: Yes Sand that is correct

Comment: and another thing they just put what ever they use in their country

Comment: This is my 2 cents on this. As you said you don't have control at the user's point but you have control there. What I like to suggest is (if you know how) to do a little modification to your data upload script. If you really don't want add the options to a drop down then re-tag them at upload point using `if ... else` or a `switch ... case` Ex: `if($propertyType = "vila" || $propertyType = "vila" ,,,, etc){ insert as "home" }`. I think something like this is what you can do.

Comment: Thank you Sand. I will probably do that as you suggest. I was thinking of doing that but just had a feeling that mysql would of had some function or something that would be like magic ! ha For the time being I am going to user WHERE PropertyType IN ( 'Apartment', 'Flat','Penthouse') and just change the query based on what they have selected

Comment: The problem is that you could search for multiple terms, but that's gonna make it slower. And you'll have to even include typos or something... While doing it before hand will make things a lot smoother for you after.

Comment: in the short term you can do an IN query, and/or process the XML before you import it, in order to recognise the property type from the possible descriptions and change them to ones you can use. But really in the long term you should be giving the providers of this info a numbered list of property types, and asking them to send you the _number_ in their dataset. Then you can match it to a table in your DB containing the numbered list, against the descriptions you want to use. Then there is no ambiguity - they can use whatever description they want at their end, and you can use yours...

Comment: ...but since you agreed in advance that number 1 means "Apartment" or "Flat" or "Penthouse" (depending on your preference) then you always know basically what they are referring to. Using unique numeric identifiers in this way also prevents the risk of silly spelling mistakes etc. Whatever they are using to generate the XML should be able to cope with a basic lookup of this kind.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a table ( say `PropertyNames` ) that matches each property name variant to its unique property type name. Then you would use a query such as the following:

`SELECT distinct a.* from PropertyTable a JOIN PropertyNames b ON b.propertyName ='$propertyName' and  a.propertyType = b.nameVariant`.

Here, the `$propertyName` refers to the unambiguous name of the property in the `PropertyNames` table, which you would use in the drop down selection.